# Global search input on React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search input in my `<Layout>` component. The UX I would like is that when you start typing in the box, it changes the URL to `/search/?=whatever` and uses the Search page to render my results. I have this mostly working but there is a persistent problem where a few characters will go missing, usually the 3rd or 4th, as things transition from the original page to the search page. The code is all up on https://github.com/coderanger/buddy.farm/ if that helps. Might be more of a generic React question but the heart of the issue seems to be navigate() forcing my input focus away from the text field while things process or something?

Comment: Debouncing the input event and setting autofocus on the element should improve it somewhat.

Comment: Actually you might have a bit of an extra dependency/race condition [here](https://github.com/coderanger/buddy.farm/blob/bb94bb9f525242fbc20073fb6571caf6c048c08a/src/pages/search.tsx#L74). It might be triggering extra renders so test it out to make sure your useEffect isn't called every time you update the search query

Comment: @AndrewGillis That definitely helped a lot, I can't reproduce it reliably anymore but in a bunch of testing it happened a handful of times so still some very small window while things are reflowing it seems. Probably good enough now though so thank you :)

Comment: @FerranBuiren The reason I think this is Gatsby related at least in part is that if I make the static query which contains the search index smaller, it shrinks the gap where keystrokes are lost, so it's at least in part related to Gatsby's data loading layer though that may just be "it's a thing which takes time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving this with three rounds of changes. First was the effect fixes mentioned by Andrew Gillis above, those were just straight up bugs. Second was to move the search index out of Gatsby page data (it was previously a static query in the page) and into its own JSON file. Shoutout to [this blog post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/downloading-gatsby-static-search-index-asynchronously/) for laying out exactly how, but the short version is to use a createPages hook to run the same GraphQL query and write it to `public/search.json`, and then write some normal React stuff to load that data when the page mounts with a loading spinner and whatnot. And then third, I used a global context to continue recording the user inputs via onChange event after a `navigate()` was started and then restore from that once the page mounts.